# How to return json from Amazon Python Lambda, that can be handled be Android GSON api

Tags: android, python, json, amazon-web-services, gson

## Problem:

lambda function return string, I can't write the correct syntax in lambda function toconvert it to json to be parsed with GSON.

## Android StudioLogs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 Process: com.innovdroid.awslambdatest, PID: 6252
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:111)
    atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:58)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:741)at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaJsonBinder.deserialize(LambdaJsonBinder.java:47)at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaInvocationHandler.processInvokeResult(LambdaInvocationHandler.java:134)at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaInvocationHandler.invoke(LambdaInvocationHandler.java:64)at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy0.GetAllSchoolsNames(Unknown Source)at com.innovdroid.awslambdatest.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:47)at com.innovdroid.awslambdatest.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:741)  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.Lamb at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaInvocationHandler.processInvokeResult(LambdaInvocationHandler.java:134) at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaInvocationHandler.invoke(LambdaInvocationHandler.java:64) at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)  at $Proxy0.GetAllSchoolsNames(Unknown Source)  at com.innovdroid.awslambdatest.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:47) at com.innovdroid.awslambdatest.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41)at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: add some code too. it help us to help u.

Comment: What does your JSON look like? What does your Java object look like? Also, did you read `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2at ` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that aws lambda return: { "/contrecords/": "6"} and that occur if you have a json and convert it to json again:

In python if you have: 
not_encoded = {"contrecords":str(item_count)} //this is json already
no need to usejson.dumps(not_encoded) //this will occuer Android GSON make error in parsing.

The mobile device can invoke lambda function  (send request and get response). but still a problem of response timeout when android device connect to amazon lambda function. If your amazon lambda in vpc, you must have a Internet Gateway and Nat Gateway. As the Nat Gateway reopen the connection with your amazon resources when timeout occur.

See:
create Python Lambda to access amazon RDS  : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html
configure your Nat Gateways for amazon lambda: 
https://blog.rackspace.com/aws-201-understanding-the-default-virtual-private-cloud